# Can you get any irrational number using square roots?

Tags: irrational-numbers, radicals

Given an irrational number, is it possible to represent it using only rational numbers and square roots(or any root, if that makes a difference)?

That is, can you define the irrational numbers in square roots, or is it something much deeper than that? Can pi be represented with square roots?

Comment: You should google for "transcendental numbers".

Comment: No. What you are describing can atmost contain those numbers that are algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$, and $\pi$ is not.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre thanks! exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Already $\sqrt[3]{2}$ cannot be expressed in terms of square roots. The numbers so expressible are called the *Euclidean constructible numbers*. The cosine of $20^\circ$ cannot be expressed in terms of square roots. This shows that the $60^\circ$ angle cannot be trisected by straightedge and compass.

Comment: Actually, almost all real numbers are _uncomputable_, which means (loosely) that there are no finite way to describe how the number should be computed. The algebraic numbers are a subset of the _countable_ set of computable numbers.

Comment: @DanielR So many sets of numbers! Do you have a reference talking briefly about all(important ones) of them, and perhaps a nice venn diagram?

Comment: @DanielR is this the same definition of "almost all" that allows you to say that "almost all integers contain the digit 1"? Or any digit for that matter. Or any sequence of digits actually

Comment: @Cruncher Sorry, couldn't find a nice reference. There are some diagrams to be found, but they didn't include the set of the computable numbers. Regarding "almost all", take a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_all).

Comment: Do you accept infinite square roots? Cause if so, then there is a formula due to Vieta expressing $\pi$ in infinitely nested square roots of 2. There's a 2 outside of the square root but that may be rectified easily by $\sqrt 4=2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The smallest set of numbers closed under the ordinary arithmetic operations and square roots is the set of [constructible numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_number). The number $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is not constructible, and this was one of the famous greek problems: the duplication of the cube.

If you allow roots of all orders, then you're talking about equations that can be solved by radicals. Galois theory explains which equations can be solved in this way. In particular, $x^5-x+1=0$ cannot. But it clearly has a real root.

Comment: is the solution to $x^5-x+1=0$ transcendental? Is it computable?

Comment: @Cruncher all solutions of $x^5-x+1=0$ are algebraic by definition. All algebraic numbers are computable.